# Интерпретация html кода на чистом ядре

Tags: html, css, linux, c, ассемблер

День добрый, вопрос может показаться странным, но все же...
Возможно ли как нибудь визуализировать html+css на чистом ядре. Для этого (я так понимаю) мне нужно ядро (предположим, это linux), далее - движок для интерпретации html,css,js (допустим, это QtWebEngine), а далее что? Можете подсказать как это вообще делается примерно и что для этого надо?

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под «чистым ядром»? И к чему такой изврат — вы и так уже используете высокоуровневую библиотеку Qt, которая ни то что ни в одном из базовых режимов — без удовлетворения кучи зависимостей прикладного уровня просто не загрузится.

Comment: Окей, а вообще такое возможно сделать ? и вообще как. Примерно. Под чистым ядром я имею в виду чистое ядро, вот к примеру я скачаю с сайта какой нибудь линукс 4 и скомпилю, вот я про это

Comment: Рекомендую посмотреть в сторону https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/KolibriOS . Там это уже всё написано.

У меня всего один вопрос: НАХРЕНА?

Answer (score 5):

Начнём с того, что у «чистого ядра» из пользовательского интерфейса только:

1. Консоль, в которую можно выводить только текст.
2. Кадровый буфер (включается в опциях загрузки ядра), на который можно выводить не только текст, но и изображения. Буфер представлен файлами устройств `/dev/fbX`, которые можно отобразить в память. Пример на англоязычном StackOverflow: «[Paint Pixels to Screen via Linux FrameBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996777/paint-pixels-to-screen-via-linux-framebuffer)».

Никакого Qt, а тем более X.Org. Всё придётся рисовать самому, попиксельно/посимвольно.

Затем, отсутствие библиотек вынуждает по сути реализовывать их же, но своими силами (доступна только стандартная библиотека Си и системные вызовы, поверх которых эта библиотека построена). Даже *Links*, браузер, работающий в консоли, имеет зависимости от дополнительных библиотек, не идущих в комплекте с системой.

Comment: не понимаю какой может быть пользовательский интерфейс у "чистого ядро" : без `init` процесса, загрузка просто остановится. Никогда не вникал как Linux-ядро разворачивается, так что поправьте если я не прав и возможно машину без userland использовать.

Comment: @jfs, Вы правы. Я сделал допущение, что всё не так плохо и «чистое ядро» это не только `vmlinuz`, но хотя бы `initramfs`.